# Google Analytics - cannot insert or update webproperty

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to create a new [WebProperty](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert) or [update](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/update) an existing one in Google Analytics API.

The service account is added to the Google Analytics account with all permissions checked.

Response:

```
"errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
        "message": "Your project does not have access to this feature."
      }
]
```

Apart from update and insert the rest of the management API is working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

it's written in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtProfileGuide):

> Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete,
>   patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources is
>   currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're
>   interested in using these features, request access to the beta.

**Update:**

To request access fill out the form at [Google Analytics Account Setup and Configuration APIs](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1xyjp6ca4YkGjh7TDi1Z3XyA3XHcRHkKzFentxzUrmPY/viewform) it can take a few weeks to get access. You should recieve an email from google when you get access.