# Google Analytics management API insert property- Insufficient Permission 403

Tags: python, google-analytics

I am having problem using python Google Analytics reports API to create new web property under account. I can get list of properties with no problem but when I try to insert it returns me 403. When I try to use API explorer it shows:
403 Forbidden

```
"errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
        "message": "Your project does not have access to this feature."
      }
]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Analytics - cannot insert or update webproperty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652867/google-analytics-cannot-insert-or-update-webproperty)

Answer (score 0):

[These API are currently in beta](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/account-management) :

> Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete, patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources is currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're interested in using these features, request access to the beta.